# Evaluate the following improper integral by using residues

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x^2+4)^2}dx$

Approach: We have to see the evaluated function as a complex function and evaluate it a long a semi-circle enclosing the upper singularities. The singularities or poles are clearly $x=3i,2i$. Now we have to find the order of the poles.  I have tried partial fractions, power series expansion, but nothing works out. I am having problems finding the order of the poles by just looking at the function. What's the trick?. Once we find the order of the poles, we can either see the residues in the series expansion or by using the equation $re=q^{m-1}(pole)/(m-1)!$ where m is the order of the pole

Comment: For rational functions, "order of the pole" = "multiplicity of the zero in the denominator". Factor

Answer (score 1):

There will be a pole at $x_0$ on account of the factors $x-x_0$ in the denominator.  Since your denominator factorises as
$$(x-3i)^1(x+3i)^1(x-2i)^2(x+2i)^2\ ,$$
there will be a pole of order $1$ at $3i$ and a pole of order $2$ at $2i$.

Comment: so they key is to factor the denominator and divide it by $x-pole$ and  see where where it becomes undefined?

Comment: Ummm... maybe, but that seems like a very complicated way of putting it.  You just look at the factorisation and see that you have $(x-3i)$ to the power $1$ and $(x-2i)$ to the power $2$.

Comment: However it is a bit more complicated if the denominator is not a polynomial, for example$$\frac{x}{\sin x}\quad\hbox{or}\quad \frac1{1-e^x}\ .$$

Comment: in that case, I would just use series. Series in this problem look messy

Comment: Another option: for the first example, at $x=\pi$ the function $\sin x$ is zero but its derivative is not.  So there is, very roughly speaking, "one factor of $x-\pi$" and the order is $1$.  For $x=0$ the same idea shows that there is "one factor of $x$" but it is cancelled by the $x$ in the numerator, so we have a pole of order $0$, or to put it more accurately, a removable singularity.

Comment: Agree that series look messy.  Use them only as a last resort.

Comment: I didn't get it. The calculations are still too messy because you have to take the derivative  of $\frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x+2i)^2}$ once, divided by $2!$ and evaluate it at $x=2i$. I didn't get it.

Comment: My algebra sucks. I did it with wolphram alpha and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For any meromorphic function $f(z)$ that is $O(|z|^{-2})$ as $|z|\to +\infty$ and takes real values over the real line, the integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\sum_{\xi\in Z}\text{Res}(f(z),z=\xi) $$
where $Z$ is the set of poles in the upper half-plane, by the residue theorem and the ML lemma.

Since $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z^2+9)(z^2+4)^2}$ is an even function and by partial fraction decomposition we have
$$\text{Res}(f(z),z=2i)=-\frac{13 i}{200},\qquad \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=3i\right)=\frac{3i}{50},$$
it follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^2\,dz}{(z^2+9)(z^2+4)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{200}}.$$